# How using where and group by for MySql

Tags: mysql, date, where-clause

I have a table in my database:

```
CREATE TABLE `yapial` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**status** and **date** columns Index. I run sql code:

```
select status, count(*) from user_details group by status
```

and success running 0.34ms. But I want to add a date restriction =>

```
select date, status, count(*) from user_details 
where date between '2017-01-25 18:13:50' and '2017-01-29 18:13:50'
group by status
```

Success running 6.52s. The time limit is too high. I want to reduce time running. How should I improve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query that takes 0.34ms is probably getting its result from the [MySQL query cache](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache.html). It's unlikely that the query is that fast.

The best optimization I think is if you have a two-column index. There are two possibilities:

```
alter table user_details
  add key (status, date),
  add key (date, status);
```

If the first index is used, it will do an index-scan but it will avoid the temporary table:

```
explain select sql_no_cache date, status, count(*) 
  from user_details use index (status) 
  where date between '2017-01-25 18:13:50' and '2017-01-29 18:13:50'
  group by status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: user_details
   partitions: NULL
         type: index
possible_keys: date,status
          key: status
      key_len: 7
          ref: NULL
         rows: 3
     filtered: 33.33
        Extra: Using where; Using index
```

If the second index is used, it will use the index to do a range lookup, matching rows by the date range, but it will cause a temporary table.

```
root@localhost [test] > explain select sql_no_cache date, status, count(*) 
    from user_details use index (date) 
    where date between '2017-01-25 18:13:50' and '2017-01-29 18:13:50' 
    group by status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: user_details
   partitions: NULL
         type: range
possible_keys: date,status
          key: date
      key_len: 5
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Which index is best depends on how many rows match the condition.

Comment: Certainly this method more performance. I try and success running 2.5s.